# touchesBegan not invoked on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I am developing a pie chart application  **using Core-Plot** on iPhone.

There are no issues in drawing the pie-chart. But I am unable to interact with its slices. I even tried interacting with them using touchesBegan event. But even this method is not getting invoked.

Please help me in this regards. User interaction has been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement `<CPPiechartDelegate>` in your class.

Then implement

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

// This will inform you the index of the slice that was touched or clicked.

}
```

Also use latest Coreplot framework as old framework has some issues related to selecting touch event.

**Edit**

**Try This**

**In yourViewController.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"

@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <CPPieChartDataSource, CPPieChartDelegate> 
{


}
```

**In yourViewController.m file**

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
NSString *selectedIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Selected index: %lu", index];
NSLog(@"You have selected index=%@",selectedIndex);
}
```

Finally view your gdb log to get the response ,which index you have selected.

Comment: I have tried this method..but it is not being called.....if I add CPPiechartDelegate protocol....its giving an error :"The protocol declaration could not be found"...Whats the latest version of the frammework?I am using CorePlot 0-1.2.2.....Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi sandeep , there is an issue in coreplot framework.This issue is already discussed http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=227#c0 & resolved.But this might be not updated in download section.As i have never integrate it so better you can your post your problem in http://code.google.com/p/core-plot.

Comment: I tried whatever is written over there its still not working for me.I am still getting the same error when I add the protocol CPPieChartdelegate.......